# Arch - prevent GUI from start

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, gdm

I just installed arch on a encrypted LVM.
After the boot process gnome3 tries to start but it looks like I installed the wrong driver. The whole system freezes, its not possible to enter another tty.

Is there a way to prevent the gui from starting direct after the boot process?

I used  `sudo systemctl enable gdm.services` to define the start of the gui.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Change_default_target_to_boot_into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arch installation media should help you here. Boot into it and follow the directions to mount your encrypted drive and then arch-chroot into the system. Once you are in, you could disable gdm.services. Alternatively, you could install the proper drivers. To be sure that the driver is the problem, you might want to check your logs while you're in there.

Comment: No need to chroot: OP can change the default target with a kernel parameter.